# how to dynamically set the "value" attribute of url tag in struts2?

Tags: java, jsp, url, struts2, ognl

I have an image `images/example.jpg` in the Struts2 project folder.

I am able to display this image by using:

```
<s:url value="/images/example.jpg" var="urlTag"></s:url>
<img src="<s:property value="#urlTag"/>" height="200" width="200"/>
```

But how to set the URL- value attribute dynamically?
I tried doing this:

```
<s:url value="<s:property value="imageLink"/>" var="urlTag"></s:url>  
/* where "imgageLink" has the value(/images/example.jpg) obtained from the action class*/
<img src="<s:property value="#urlTag"/>" height="200" width="200"/>
```

The above code gives an error:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /display.jsp (line: 28, column: 45) equal symbol expected
```

(i.e. before `imageLink` in the above code)

Please suggest any solutions for this.

Note: I have successfully done image transfer using `inputstream`, but I rather want to work it out using Struts `url` tag.

Comment: Where are you setting imageLink variable? Did you tried #imageLink with value attribute of s:url.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't place struts tags in the struts tag attribute. Try

```
<s:url value="%{imageLink}" var="urlTag"/>
```

provide the `getImageLink()` in the action class.

Comment: "%{imageLink}" did the job and #imageLink didn't work.